# upload local photo from pc to facebook user profile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use facebook api to share a photo from laptop to user's facebook wall ,
Is it possible to use a path like that in sdk javascript code ?

```
FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {source: 'file:///C:/wamp/www/facebook/me.jpg'}, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.error;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.id;
    }
  });
```

If not , what should i do ?

Comment: no, you can´t just share a local file. take a look at the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Comment: see "multipart/form-data"